# Non-Work energy conversion

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, work

Are there any conversions of energy that are not considered work, (energy change with a force and displacement)? For example heat transfer does not convert the form of energy, can something such as joule heating be considered a conversion from electrical energy to heat, or is there a hidden motion that allows us to describe this as 'work'? We often use the term 'power' for certain conversions where the 'displacement' and motion is not obvious.

Comment: Force–displacement work is only one type of work. One also has electrical work (moving a charge within a field or polarizing a material), magnetic work, stress–strain work, etc. Any energy transfer that isn't heat or mass transfer can generally by characterized as work. In Joule heating, work is done on the charge carriers, and the associated energy is subsequently dissipated in the form of thermal energy. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: Work can be considered to be a form of energy.

Answer (score 1):

Work is a more general concept than a force acting through a distance.

The mechanics branch of physics primarily addresses work for a point particle, or a rigid body, for which there is no change in the internal energy (temperature, phase, chemical composition, etc.) of the body.  Here, work done by a force is defined as $\int_{r_1}^{r_2} \vec F \cdot d \vec  r$ where $\vec F$ is the force and $\vec r$ is the displacement.  The change in kinetic energy is equal to the net work done by all forces on the body. (For a conservative force, the negative of the work done by the force can be considered as the difference in potential energy.)

Thermodynamics considers the change in internal energy of a system, and work in thermodynamics is a much broader concept than work in mechanics. In thermodynamics work is defined as "energy transferred without mass transfer across the boundary of a system because of an intensive property difference other than temperature between the system and its surroundings". Using this definition, electrical current flowing in/out of a system is work. Heat is defined as "energy transferred without mass transfer across the boundary of a system solely because of a difference in temperature between the system and its surroundings". Mass transfer is addressed using the difference between the enthalpy entering and exiting an open system. See a good thermodynamics text such as one by Obert, or one by Sonntag and Van Wylen.  Power is the rate of work or the rate of heat transfer.

Even for a body that has a change in internal energy, the mechanics definition of work is accurate when applied to the center of mass of the system.

To distinguish between these two definitions of work, some use the name pseudowork for the work defined in mechanics and reserve work to mean work as defined in thermodynamics. You can find discussions of this approach on the web under "pseudowork" and/or articles written by Sherwood.

Answer (score 0):

In thermodynamics, work is a macroscopic notion, as a piston being moved againt some load. We could think of a kind of work-energy stuff when heat increases the kinetic energy of a gas (by increasing its temperature). But microscopic states like that are beyond the concept of work.